# Can I do AC analysis of a transistor solely using the input/output impedances provided by the datasheet?

Tags: transistors, small-signal

I learned to do AC small signal analysis of a BJT transistor with dV/dI ~ re = 26mV/Ie. But I don't understand why we take Vbe as 26mV here. Also, in the datasheets, I found graphs of input/output impedances for the transistor. Can't I just use them for a more precise calculation? If so, how to do it? I mean what would be the resulting equivalent circuit?

[image: Input Impedance]
[image: Output Admittance]

Let's assume Ic=10mA. Then it would follow that Zi=500 Ω and Zo=1/(65 μS) = 15,400 Ω = 15k4Ω.
Now that I have found these impedances, how should I place them in my equivalent circuit?

[image: re model]

Re model was like this. But I don't know about what I should change.

Comment: You mean \$V_T\$, the thermal voltage, is about \$26\:\text{mV}\$ (at room temps.) Just the result of an equi-partition rule (energy of \$\frac12 k T\$ goes into each possible degree of freedom in a system) and large number population statistics used in statistical thermodynamics. A little bit of exposure to applying a few ideas and you can come up with it entirely on your own. Hand-waving, the idea of it is a quantitative measure when saying *"there is, on average, this much energy per jostling charge at this temperature."*

Comment: You have hie and hoe. You need also hre and hfe ... Parameters of "hybrid" model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That 26 millivolts is not Vbe. It's a quantity seen in common basic nonlinear operating laws of diodes and transistors. Your formula 26mV/Ie is resistance Re in a linearized AC-only analysis model for transistors. Ie is the idle state (=operating point) value of the emitter current. The linearized model can be used properly for AC-signals which have peak values only few percents of the idle state DC values.

See for ex. this article of h-parameter AC model of a bipolar transistor.
https://bestengineeringprojects.com/h-parameter-model-for-transistor/

The parameters are different for all three basic amplifier configurations of BJT.

Using parameters is tricky and their actual values can vary wildly between the individuals of the same transistor type. The calculations must be done with complex number phasors in high frequencies. They are still useful when one tries to make statistical yield forecasts for a mass produced product or to see with calculations if his circuit idea has any chances to work. Without knowing the parameter values exactly (=measure them in the operating point) any accurate calculations are impossible.  Taking the typical values from datasheets can easily cause large errors if you design a device which you are going to build just once. But as said, statistical analysis is possible if the distributions of the parameter values are known.

Circuits are generally designed so that the variations of the values of the h-parameters can be compensated to some degree. There are adjustments and preferably feedback which makes the actual h-parameter values less important as long as there's enough gain. Unfortunately the high frequency phase lag (=slowness) of transistors make feedback in radio frequencies less effective. But one can make the feedback to adjust the operating point to get the total gain right in a radio frequency amplifier.